# What is Special Permissions?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, file-permissions, acl

I was checking the security rights for the folder `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks` and find that Authenticated Users group has Special Permissions (notice that it has **no Write permissions**):

[image]

I went into Advanced tab and the basic view is (notice that it has **no Read permissions**):

[image]

But when I clicked "Show advance permissions", it shows an additional "Read permissions":

[image]

Why does it say different things for the same folder in the three views? What is the actual access that the group Authenticated Users have on this folder?

Comment: What do you mean by “different things”? “Read permissions” is not “Permission to read” but instead the ability to read the ACL.

Answer (score 2):

Lets try two more ways to show the permissions:

**icacls.exe:**

```
 NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:(CI)(W,Rc)
```

**Get-Acl:**

```
 NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users Allow  Write, ReadPermissions, Synchronize
```

Your second and third screenshot actually show very similar permissions, the third one being the most precise.

I think the `Write` permissions should also be shown in the first screenshot, this may be a bug, but permissions can be complicated.

About **Read**:

on the first two screenshops `Read` means being able to read the contents of the file/folder, on the third screenshot they list advanced permissions, `Read permissions` means being able to read the NTFS permissions of the object, not the content itself.
These are two different things.

Comment: why my `get-acl` only returns really basic information... no special permissions mentioned...
PS D:\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Archive> get-acl .\master.mdf                                                       

    Directory: D:\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\Archive


Path       Owner                  Access
----       -----                  ------
master.mdf BUILTIN\Administrators BUILTIN\Administrators Allow  FullControl...

Answer (score 0):

Found some useful documents:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_descriptor
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc783530(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN